# Clicking on databound ComboBoxItem doesn't update the parent ComboBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-4.0

I am binding a dictionary to a ComboBox ItemSource.  Everything binds properly, however when I run the program, click on the drop down, then click on the item...nothing happens.

Other useful information, when I click the text of each item, i can see a faint box/border around the text.  If I click inside the box, nothing happens.  If I click outside the box, things work as expected.  Thoughts?

My xaml code:

```
<ComboBox Name="PayloadDrop">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <ItemContainerTemplate>
         <ComboBoxItem Tag="{Binding Path=Key}" 
             Content="{Binding Path=Value}" />
         </ItemContainerTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And my code behind:

```
Dim PayloadDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Int16, String) From _
        {{0, "Some payload text"}, {1, "Path to a payload file"}}

PayloadDrop.ItemsSource = PayloadDictionary
```

Below is a screenshot of what my combo box looks like...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Instead of ItemContainerTemplate use DataTemplate. Nothing happens you mean selected item is not displayed in ComboBox?

Comment: By "Nothing happens" I meant that, literally, nothing would happen.  None of my onclick events would fire (not shown in the code above), the combo box selected item wouldn't change to the item that I clicked, and the drop down box wouldn't get hidden again.  Basically, the screenshot that you see above would just stay there...Once I changed my code from "ComboBoxItem" to "TextBlock" and the "Content" attribute to "Text", everything started working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never had much experience with ItemContainerTemplate, but as far as I understand, the case will be the same with DataTemplate. (There is no mention of Resources or MenuBase or StatusBar)

You have collection of KeyValuePair items as ItemsSource. KeyValuePair is not ComboBoxItem, so ComboBox decides to create container for it - ComboBoxItem. This container needs a way to display item data, and you have set ItemTemplate for that, as a result **another** ComboBoxItem is created inside container. So, you have ComboBoxItem inside ComboBoxItem. External ComboBoxItem is connected with ComboBox, so ComboBox recieves clicks. Internal ComboBoxItem is displayed with faint border and is disconnected, so there is no reaction to click events.
 
There are two possible ways to change your xaml: either use correct DataTemplate for ItemTemplate, or Style for ItemContainerStyle. As I understand, your task is to display Value but preserve information about Key (ID of some kind) as well, so you should use correct DataTemplate:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="PayloadDrop">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In this case ComboBox will display only value. You can access it with SelectedValue property. SelectedItem property will contain underlying KeyValuePair. Since KeyValuePair does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, it is essential to use Mode=OneTime to evade memory leaks.

Comment: Uggg...Changing it from a combo item to a textblock fixed it...so much wasted time...Thanks a lot.  Thanks to @SamTheDev as well.  Obviously I didn't realize the comboboxitem was automatically created...

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to define a `ComboboxItem`  inside the `DataTemplate`, since it will be created implicitly

```
<ComboBox Name="PayloadDrop" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Tag="{Binding Path=Key}" Padding="0" Margin="0"
         Text="{Binding Path=Value}" >                       
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```